# Storing Partial Form Completions

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

We're using Solspace Freeform for a multi-stage application form on a client site. We need to store each stage in the CMS - is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question a couple of months back. I was told that it would require some advanced customization to the plugin. It sounded like a pretty big project.